# Deploying azure storage fileServices/shares - error: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rm-template

As part of a durable function app deployment, I am deploying azure storage.
On deploying the fileServices/shares, I am getting the following error:

```
error": {
        "code": "InvalidHeaderValue",
        "message": "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.\nRequestId:6c0b3fb0-701a-0058-0509-a8af5d000000\nTime:2022-08-04T13:49:24.6378224Z"
    }
```

I would appreciate any advice as this is eating up a lot of time and I am no closer to resolving it.

Section of arm template for the share deployment is below:

```
   {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
      "apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccount1_name'), '/default/FuncAppName')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices', parameters('storageAccount1_name'), 'default')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccount1_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized",
        "shareQuota": 5120,
        "enabledProtocols": "SMB"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer to this: removing the property "accessTier": "TransactionOptimized" resolves the issue. The default value for this is TransactionOptimized.

Although the template exported from azure portal includes this property, deployment fails if this parameter is present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Premium storage account.

'TransactionOptimized' access tier is available for storage account kind 'StorageV2' and SKU 'Standard_LRS'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?tabs=azure-cli#change-the-tier-of-an-azure-file-share